# l.Slow loading of an app when implementing admob ads - Android

Tags: android, performance, admob

This is really quick question. I tried implementing simple banner ad for my app, got it working fine, but now entire app loads really slow. I get like 7-8seconds of white screen before my activity loads up. If I try to remove the ads, I am back at 1-2 seconds.

I think I might be doing something wrong.

This is my adView in XML:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/reklama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="my ad unit id"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And this is how I load up the ads in MainActivity in onCreate method.

```
        // Init ad
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "my app key");
    // Load ad
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.reklama);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

When I start app with the ads, I get greeted with white screen for solid 
 7-8 seconds. Tried Nexus 5x and Pixel. Is there a way to speed things up or maybe load the activity first and then load the ads in background? I won't mind if the ads take time to load up, if user could interact with the app already.

I tried turning off the Instant Run as recommended in other threads and it had no effect at all.

Comment: I didn't work with admob before, just passing by but you may want to hide ca-app-pub part, looks like a personal key. Edit: Also apparently making ads run on delay helps the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490596/admob-better-performance-in-android-activity

Comment: thanks, got disconnected while typing this and it resulted in some weird editing :)